# LESS Passing multiple value in single variable

Tags: less

I'm pretty new to less, so i was wondering if what i have done have sense..
Unfurtunately i can't test the less code, so i am asking to you...

Basically i want to passing multiple value to a single less var without use mixins:

Here what i have do:

```
@button-disable: #aea79f;
@title-card: font-size:36px, font-weight:lighter, line-height:29px, color:@button-disable;
```

Is title-card well formatted?
Should i do this kind of things?

It have sense to do a work in this way in less?

Thank you

Comment: It might not be relevant to you anymore, but I had to update my answer, because I wasn't aware of detached rulesets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but your given syntax is not correct. In some scenarios you might want to use a [list](http://lesscss.org/functions/#list-functions) of values, e.g. for iterating over them in a loop. This looks similar to your proposal:

```
@list: "banana", "tomato", "potato", "peach";
```

But what you are looking for is a [detached ruleset](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature):

```
@detached-ruleset: {
  font-size: 36px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  line-height: 29px;
  color:@button-disable;
};

.class {
    @detached-ruleset(); 
}
```